# OSX Lion AFP multiple requests to NAS

Tags: macos, network, sharing, nas, afp

I've got 8 TB of NAS shared with a network of mostly MacOSX Lion iMacs via AFP.

Right after opening the share, the computer starts to send an enormous amount of FPEnumerateExt2 requests, trying to get the sizes of the shared files and calculate sizes of folders.

Multiply it by several computers, and network and NAS quickly gets flooded by the requests rendering it borderline unusable. Is there any way to stop it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how you can disable the calculation of folders:

- In Finder.app press **CMD+J**.
- **uncheck** "calculate folder sizes"
- Click the button on the bottom to set it as the **default behavior**
- Press **CMD+J** again to hide the panel.